# Sending Camel HTTP Post custom body

Tags: java, http, spring-boot, apache-camel

I am new to Apache camel. I am trying to create routes to call multiple rest APIs and aggregate the response into one.
But for some reason, the JSON request that I am creating does not reach the rest endpoint. 
During debug, I see that Exchange objects do have the values that I have set and get converted into byte array and on the other side, rest API recieves empty objects.

I am working on a Spring boot project and I have tried different ways of marshalling the request to JSON including Gson and Jackson. None of which seem to work.

Please assist.

```
from("direct:oneResponse")
        .multicast(new MyAggregationStrategy()).parallelProcessing()
        .to("direct:rest1call", "direct:rest2call")
        .end();


from("direct:rest1call")
        .routeId("rest1call")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .setHeader("Accept", constant("application/json"))
        .process(new Processor() {              
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn().setBody(<<valid json>>); //json values as required for the rest call.
            }
        })
        .to("http4://localhost:5555/mock/rest1call")
        .setProperty("route", simple("routeId"))
        .unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(Rest1Response.class));

from("direct:rest2call")
        .routeId("rest2call")
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
        .setHeader("Content-Type", constant("application/json"))
        .setHeader("Accept", constant("application/json"))
        .process(new Processor() {              
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getIn().setBody(<<valid json>>); //json values as required for the rest call.
            }
        })
        .to("http4://localhost:5555/mock/rest2call")
        .setProperty("route", simple("routeId"))
        .unmarshal(new JacksonDataFormat(Rest2Response.class));
```

Comment: What you have looks OK to me. Is your <<valid json>> simply a string? Can you change your rest api to just receive a String and check it gets the value from exchange? If you add a .log("${body}") just be for the .to("http...) you'll see what it's going to send.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes. the <<valid json>> is just a string containing valid json which gets printed when I add .log("${body}"). Changed the rest API to receive a String but when I run the program, it receives null.

Comment: I'm using version 2.22.2 and it works OK for me. Sorry, but I can't see what's up with your route.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try to create a processor and specify all the headers and body in it?

```
.process(new Processor() {              
            @Override
            public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethod.POST);
                exchange.getOut().setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
                exchange.getOut().setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                /* this is one way, string representation of json, but maybe you can try to build Model and fill that model with data */
                exchange.getIn().setBody(<<valid json>>); //json values as required for the rest call.
            }
        })
```

if you decide to go with models, use marshaling after processor just to be sure your data is converted to JSON.

```
.marshal(yourDataFormat)
```

Try GsonDataFormat it works pretty good for me.